# Access elements in FragmentActivity from a Fragment object

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, fragmentpageradapter

I have a FragmentActivity with a FragmentPagerAdapter which holds a number of Fragment objects through which I can slide with a horizontal swipe.

I was wondering if I can access an element ("elementToBeChanged") in the FragmentActivity from within a Fragment object? I would like to pass a String from the Fragment class to TextView element which is in the FragmentActivity object.

```
public class GalleryPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

private TextView elementToBeChanged;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.setContentView(R.layout.gallery_pager);

    elementToBeChanged = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTop);
    elementToBeChanged.setOnClickListener(this);

}
}
```

How would I have to do this? The TextView element has to be updated every time a Fragment object comes into sight (with a swipe).

It should look something like this:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentActivity fa;
private LinearLayout ll;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fa = super.getActivity();

    ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_fragment, container, false);
...
// ////////
// UPDATE THE "TextView elementToBeChanged" object in the parent FragmentActivity class HERE WHENEVER THIS FRAGMENTS BECOMES ACTIVE/VISIBLE...
// ////////

    return ll;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your GalleryPagerActivity create a function such as updateTextView(String text). That function will set the `TextView` to whatever the input value is.  Then in your GalleryFragment simply call this function with the text to be displayed as such:

```
    ((GalleryPagerActivity)getActivity()).updateTextView("my text");
```

Comment: And what can i do for opposite situation? I want to update a element in fragment, from fragmentActivity. I followed this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486952/get-id-of-textview-in-fragment-from-fragmentactivity-in-viewpager ;;;;; But they said "Do not create new object each time you set text. Use the same fragment object which you use for view pager.". How can i access to that fragmentObject? So i followed this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035090/how-to-get-existing-fragments-when-using-fragmentpageradapter ;;;; But i don't know what to do now!

Comment: Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity