# How to get a Fragment instance from FragmentActivity which contains a ViewPager for fragment transactions?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `FragmentActivity` with the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and the view pager class is as follows:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            // profile fragment activity
            Fragment f = new ProfileFragment();
            return new ProfileFragment();
        case 1:
            // radar fragment activity
            return new RadarFragment();
        case 2:
            // matches fragment activity
            return new MatchesFragment();
    }

    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 3;
  }
}
```

I also have a `BroadcastReceiver` class that has an instance variable of my custom `FragmentActivity`. Through this instance variable I would like to obtain any of the fragments above. I understand there are `FragmentManager.findFragmentById()` and `findFragmentByTag()` methods but I cant seem to find a way of using that in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have 3 pages (3 fragments), I recommend that you use the `FragmentPagerAdapter` rather than the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Then, you can use `findFragmentByTag` to find your fragments - read more about that in [This SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035090/how-to-get-existing-fragments-when-using-fragmentpageradapter)