# Fragment already added IllegalStateException with only one copy of fragment

Tags: android

I know there have been several questions about this exception, however, I'm experiencing this exception with only one assignment while using the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

I indicated the line I'm experiencing the crash on below while setting up the adapter and pager.

**Setting up my `Fragment`s:**

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
t.add(0, new StarTabFragment(), "starTab");
t.add(0, new HierarchiesTabFragment(), "hierarchyTab");
t.add(0, new GroupsTabFragment(), "groupTab");
t.add(0, new VehiclesTabFragment(), "hierarchyTab");
t.commit();
```

**Setting up my adapter and pager:**

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) mDrawerLayoutRight.findViewById(R.id.pager);
PagerTabStrip tabs = (PagerTabStrip) mDrawerLayoutRight.findViewById(R.id.pager_tab_strip);
tabs.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.RED);

CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(customPagerAdapter.getCount() - 2);
viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter); //crashing here
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new LoopingPageChangeListener(viewPager));
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:876)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: StarTabFragment{d12eb55 #1 id=0x7f0b0116 starTab}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1197)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:673)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:447)
    at com.company.activities.MapsActivity.setupSliderRight(MapsActivity.java:847)
    at com.company.activities.MapsActivity.access$2100(MapsActivity.java:112)
    at com.company.activities.MapsActivity$DBHierarchyResponseReceiver.onReceive(MapsActivity.java:2287)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that I was pre-adding the `Fragment`s to the manager. `FragmentPagerAdapter` automatically adds all `Fragment`s to the manager in the `getItem()` method.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14039416/981242) for details on the `getItem()` method.

Answer (score 14):

It seems sometimes that this is a generic error thrown when something occurred while loading the fragment.

For example: I had this error when inside `onCreateView` I called `findViewById` with a wrong id that didn't exist on fragment's layout.

So, make sure your fragment `onCreateView`'s code doesn't has any bug (try commenting it all - only returning the raw inflated view - and see if it still throws this error.

Comment: Thank you, this saved a lot of time!

Comment: This comment is still useful. I findViewById to a wrong class, and got this error too. So weird why don't they just throw error like "Cannot cast class...." in my case...

Answer (score 9):

Its not necessary that problem is in with the way you are adding fragments. As i faced similar issue and later when i used debugger to go step by step to find real issue it turned out issue was with views in fragment layout.

I was getting similar exception like yours but real exception was

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
```

Comment: Why down vote? You should reproduce the above issue first before down voting.

Comment: You were right, I debugged the app step by step and found out that problem was elsewhere, thank you

Comment: @Amin Keshavarzian Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @jatin rana I've faced with the same issue related to fragment layout. And your comment helped me to resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: @IgorOK Great buddy.

Comment: Man, I can't believe it! The stacktrace did not point me the ClassCastException. Lucky me that forgot a breakpoint in one rxjava callback error in subscribe which pointed me the stack trace to the view with the wrong cast!

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if there are a lot of people who could be facing this issue due the same reason as me, but one tiny error that *transitively* kept causing `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added` was that I was using a custom `Fragment` class.

In the `onCreateView` method, where I inflated my layout using `inflater.inflate()`, I forgot to use the method with `attachToRoot` as **`false`**. The moment I fixed this, my issue was resolved.

**Explanation:**

The method with signature:

`inflate(@LayoutRes int resource, @Nullable ViewGroup root)`

returned `root` (parent `ViewGroup`) and not the root of the newly inflated `View`. From the JavaDocs:

> @return: The root `View` of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied, this is
>   the root `View`; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.

A similar case could happen if you use the method:
`inflate(@LayoutRes int resource, @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)` with `attachToRoot : true`.

The `Fragment` tries to add the root layout *as a child of itself*, which causes
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent`

which snowballs into our original `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added`.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the exact same problem, and it turned out to be caused by copying of the fragment code.
Android studio automatically refactored the methods, so I got this:

```
    public static Fragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
    PurchaseOfferFragment frag = new PurchaseOfferFragment();
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return  frag;
}
```

insteaf of this:

```
    public static PurchaseOfferFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
    PurchaseOfferFragment frag = new PurchaseOfferFragment();
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return  frag;
}
```

resultin in the untrackable IlleGalStateException.

Causing the error which I couldn't track with the exception being thrown.
Simply changing "Fragment" to PurchaseOfferFragment  fixed the issue 100%.

Check if your fragment names are correct in the static mathods, while making a copy and paste from existing fragments, to save some hours that I have lost!