# How to call fragment's method from activity Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this kind of structure

1. MainPage Activity1 has view pager holding 3 fragments
2. I am using tabapdater
3. The first of the fragments have method to move to another Activity2

I want to fire some method in the first fragment when button is clicked in Activity2

Can i do that? can you guys give me any example code for it??

Thanks guys

Comment: You want to change the first fragment from the second activity...am I right?

Comment: yeah that is right is it possible?

Comment: I just want to pass some object from the second activity to the first fragment

Comment: I have a solution,but first let me know if you mean FragmentPagerAdapter instead of tabadapter?

Comment: give me a second please

Comment: I have TabAdapter class. It extends FragmentPagerAdapter. and I am using it to create the fragment

Comment: You should use @DavidH in comments, otherwise other users won't get notified. You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/2036537 for passing objects between Activities. Anyway, I think that your Activity2 could be replaced with a fragment instead, but idk how exactly your app works.

Comment: Might be useful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions.
The first one I think is `startActivityForResult`. If you start your second activity by calling `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` you can expect the result in first activity by overriding the `onActivityResult` method and then change the first fragment content from there.

Another good and easy solution is using Buses like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).
They are well documented.

Answer (score 0):

In your Fragment class:

```
public void foo(Object objectToPassFromActivity) {
    // do what you want
}
```

In Your activity:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(R.id.yourViewPagerId, fragmentPosition);
fragment.foo(objectToPassFromActivity)
```

Add method:

```
private String getFragmentTag(int viewPagerId, int fragmentPosition) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + fragmentPosition;
}
```

You can see the link that i added in comments to get more details.

Comment: should put fragment id in the xml file?

Comment: should i put fragment Id in the xml file?

Comment: cause i am creating the fragment in TabAdapter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035090/how-to-get-existing-fragments-when-using-fragmentpageradapter, use findFragmentByTag instead of findFragmentById.