# How to get elements of fragments created by ViewPager in MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have several fragments which are organized with a `ViewPager`. I add an `addOnPageChangeListener` to the `ViewPager` in MainActivity's `onCreate` method which gives the position of the selected fragment.

Even though I prevent the fragments from destroying themselves with stating a `setOffscreenPageLimit`, I still haven't figured out how to access fragments from MainActivity, as simply using `findViewById` returns null object exceptions.

**What I want to do:**

I would like to access elements of fragments, e.g. layouts and scrollviews, in the `OnPageListener` of the `ViewPager`:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {

        if(i == 0) {
            // Do something with the first fragment.
        } else if(i == 1) {
            // Do something with the second fragment.
        }

    }

}
```

The `ViewPager` uses a `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Fragment1.newInstance(position);
            case 1:
                return Fragment2.newInstance(position);
            case 2:
                return Fragment3.newInstance(position);
            case 3:
                return Fragment4.newInstance(position);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Which is added like this:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

~

**Or should I change my approach?**

If accessing fragments cannot be achieved with this design, what could be an effective alternative route?

I've tried to implement `ViewPager.onPageChangeListener` in the custom `ViewPager`, but it didn't seem to be a good option.

I could deal with the elements in their respective fragments, but this is a tedious process and hard to maintain, which I the reason I look for a way to handle them simultaneously.

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I didn't find a solution in them.

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing the ViewPager's adapter code.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have added the adapter's code now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the only *"safe"* way to do it is to check the source code of `FragmentPagerAdapter`, and see what `tag` is the fragment is added with - because `findFragmentByTag` is the only safe way to get a Fragment from a FragmentManager.

Of course, we need to hope that this implementation detail doesn't change between support library versions, but it actually hasn't changed in years :)

---

Anyways, so FragmentPagerAdapter says:

> ```
>     // Do we already have this fragment?
>     String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
>     Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
> ```

So what is `name`?

> ```
> private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
>     return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
> }
> ```

What is `viewId` and what is `id`?

ViewId is `container.getId()`, where `container` is the `ViewPager` itself.

`id` is: `final long itemId = getItemId(position);` which by default is `return position;`.

---

**So you can find the Fragment as follows:**

```
Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" + fragmentPosition);
// if fragment is null, it was not created yet by ViewPager
```

---

**NOTE:**

It is worth noting that you should NOT rely on `getItem(int position) {` to return *the same fragment instance as you passed in*, because that will lead you to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753099/app-crash-after-activity-has-been-killed-in-background/55754360#55754360). (This question does it correctly, the `getItem()` method must always return a new Fragment instance.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I just tested it inside the `onPageSelected` of the ViewPager's `onPageChangeListener` and it returned the correct fragments. I'll come back to you when I've done some more testing. Right, so next would be to find a view of the selected fragment.

Comment: It works very well, thank you! Wish I could give a higher reward as it deserves it.