# Changing text of TextView is not working

Tags: android, textview, android-viewpager, onactivityresult

I want to change text of `TextView`in `onActivityResult`method. It seems like it's set correctly, but I can't see it in `view`.

That `TextView`is in third `Fragment` of `ViewPager`.

So here is my **code**:

```
public class TabsFacturasActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
        //...
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
       //...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                adjunto = true;
                // Get the Uri of the selected file 
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                // Get the path
                String path = "";
                try {
                    path = MyUtility.getPath(this, uri);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    myApplication.throwException(this);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String imgName = path.split("/")[path.split("/").length-1];
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lectura, null, false);
                textViewImg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUrlImgLectura);
                System.out.println("text view before: "+textViewImg.getText()); //It returns correct value "..."
                textViewImg.setText(imgName);
                textViewImg.invalidate(); //It does nothing
                System.out.println("text view after: "+textViewImg.getText()); //It returns correct value with image path
                filePath = path;
            }
            break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String[] titles = { "VER FACTURAS", "VER CONSUMO", "INTRODUCIR LECTURA" };

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return titles[position];
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0
                return new FacturasActivity();
            case 1: // Fragment # 1
                return new ConsumoActivity();
            case 2:// Fragment # 2
                return new LecturaActivity(); //TextView is here
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return titles.length;
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, I've tried using `invalidate`, but it does nothing. How can I solve that issue?

Comment: where you add the `View view` in the fragment view?

Comment: I've updated my question. `TextView`is in third `Fragment` (LecturaActivity).

Comment: you are inflating a new `activity_lectura` but you did not add it in the Fragment's View

Comment: How do I have to add it?

Comment: First thing why you are not using the Fragment's View? take the reference of "textViewUrlImgLectura" from Fragment view.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486952/get-id-of-textview-in-fragment-from-fragmentactivity-in-viewpager) is my previous question.

Comment: this will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/18487696/1436931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487696/1088643

I get the instance of my `Fragment` and access methods here:

```
LecturaActivity lecturaFragment = (LecturaActivity) 
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                           "android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":"+2);
lecturaFragment.changeImgText(imgName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `textViewImg.requestLayout();`

Comment: I've set it after `textViewImg.setText(imgName)`and it does nothing.

Comment: Are you sure your code is being performed? did you try to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

There could be something wrong with your fragments. May be there is another textview with the same id in another fragment that you might have loaded, and the text is being set their. Try printing the values of the textview ids.

Comment: he is inflating a new View `activity_lectura`...and never add it in the Fragment's View

Comment: I am guessing, the pager adapter being used here, is loading multiple pages/fragments to the main activity.